# Assuming collision , are there fundamental forces associated with absorbtion?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, forces, photoelectric-effect

I just learned that strong and weak nuclear forces relate to decay/emission.
I know absorbtion depends on Energy levels(QM) and heat(thermodynamics , kinetic energy , entropy) and E = gamma mc^2 ( special relativity).
Assuming collision , are there fundamental forces associated with absorbtion ?

I add that I am not an expert in QM.

Edit : I noticed my question is not so good , but that was because of my ignorance. My apologies.

Comment: uh... this really doesn't make much of any sense

Comment: Well in the mean while I read that absorbtion (if I understand correct ) does not exist in physics , its INTERACTION. That would be part of an answer I guess , which makes the question imho valid. I wonder if you downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the fundamental level there are [four forces associated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_forces) with the interactions of particles in the microcosm: the strong, the weak, the electromagnetic and the gravitational one.

The last two are long range forces and influence the behavior of matter macroscopically too, in a collective manner.

Macroscopically phenomena of absorption can be observed which at the microscopic level end up being interactions of fundamental particles. For example: a sponge absorbs the water.A black wall absorbs the visible light falling on it etc. At the microscopic level all these are interactions of the electromagnetic field of the molecules and atoms with the incoming particles (water molecules or photons in the two examples).

One has to be clear about the scale of the phenomenon.